# How can we check if email is coming from mobile

Tags: asp.net, email

Is there any way to check if email is sent from mobile phone/source. Is there any information like this in email headers? Please suggest best way to find this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract the user-agent from the mail-header. The user-agent should contain the information you need.